# How to make a chordal analysis when you only have 2 voices?

Tags: voice-leading, counterpoint

[image]

In my textbook Harmony and Voice Leading 5th edition I am to complete an exercise using 2 voices and wanted to make an analysis first of what chords were implied by the bass and soprano. Can someone help me figure out the remaining chords indicated by question marks?

Comment: The piece is in Ab major. The first ? has c, ab and f, so it could be f minor. But rather we should treat this as staying in the chord of Db major, but progressing to a 2-chord in Db major (i.e. 7th in the bass), which correctly resolves to a g diminshed chord as 6 chord, which progresses to a eb dom7 (V). The following ? again keeps this V, but progresses into a 2 chord with the 7th in the bass, which correctly resolves to a 6-chord on Ab major (I). The following ? is then Db major (IV), the next one is something like a dominant, so you could take this as Eb, although we only get the bb.

Comment: Shouldnt the last one be a Bb dominant not an Eb dominant? there is a root and 7th of a Bb7 chord

Comment: and what is a "2 chord"? do you mean ii chord? That chord does not "resolve" to I6 in functional harmony

Comment: No, the last one serves the function of an Eb dominant chord and resolves into Ab major. It is just a bit bare, but one could argue that the Eb chord is prepared by the previous chords. A "2 chord" is a seventh chord with the seventh in the bass, similar to how a 6 chord has the third in the bass and a 46 chord has the fifth in the bass, or in terms of seventh chords, 56 chord for the third and 34 chord for the fifth.

Comment: Ah ok.. I call that a 42 chord. But I am confused how you were able to label that as having dominant function if the only other note is a 7th above the bass. why would that last one have dominant function. It is ^2 not ^5. Even if the Ab is an accented PT it still leaves only one note scale degree ^2.

Comment: Well, as I said that run and the bass before do suggest some more dominant notes, we get eb, g bb and db in the bass. But then you also need to look at how it is resolved.  Here we have I - IV - ? - I. The chords that would fit the Bb would be Eb (which works well in this case as V), Bb minor 7, which as II would not readily resolve into Ab major, or G diminished, which would be counted as a variant of the dominant. So considering the resolution there is not much possibility there. You could take this as Bb, but this would then imply a progression into a dominant, which we totally do not have.

Comment: You could try to start some modulative approaches, and take this as B minor 7, then let the bass jump into an eb, giving you a 46 on I, then chromatically take up the eb to an e, giving you an Ab augmented, and then going into an f, making this an F minor 7, which could then somehow fall to B, but this would change the chordal colour quite a bit.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I get this. It seems coming from 4 part to 2 part it is much harder.... one would think it should be easier in 2 voices

Comment: I don't think you have to assign chords to every place where the bass note changes. To complete your assignment, sure maybe you do, but to get an understanding of the piece I think you can just call the first two question marks passing notes in the same chord. Your last two question marks can be roughly chalked up as a V7 chord, but just play it and see how it feels. Does it feel like it wants to resolve to I?

Comment: Thanks Nigel. It does feel like it wants to go to I, but I wanted to know why.... I think that Db in the 4th bar becomes an implied V42 with the augmented 4th interval before going to ^2 so I think this already sets up the dominant 7 sound